# Multithreading and semaphores to simulate an Elevator

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

So, I have a project where I am simulating an elevator using threads and semaphores. So, i'm using an arrayList to store what floors the elevator will go to. There are 49 people and only 7 can go in at the time. I cant use sync or sleep or availablePermits for logic. So what I am stuck at is having the elevator signal the thread to exit the elevator at their appropriate floor. I was told I should use an array to store semaphores for when the elevator goes to their floor they will signal the thread to exit. I don't fully understand how I could code this. I understand how to store the values in the array, but the part where how I would use that to trigger the passenger is what I don't get. And the thread itself will print that it leaves

**Simulator**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    public class Simulator 
    {
        //Creates ArrayList

   static ArrayList<Integer> visit_floors = new ArrayList<Integer();
        static ArrayList<Person> passengers = new ArrayList<>();

        static volatile int currentFloor;
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {

            //Creates elevator and PassengerThread
            Thread elevator = new Thread(new Elevator());
            Threads passenger = new Threads();
            elevator.start();
            passenger.startThreads();
            Collections.sort(visit_floors);
            clearDupl();
        //  System.out.println(visit_floors);
            //System.out.println(Elevator.Passenger);
        }


        public static void clearDupl()
        {
            visit_floors = new ArrayList<Integer>(new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(visit_floors));
        }

    }
```

**Threads**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Threads 
{
private int numThreads = 49;
public Thread passengerT[] = new Thread[numThreads];
private int num;
    public static int RandomFloor()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int floor = random.nextInt(6) + 2;
        return floor;
    }
     public void startThreads() throws Exception
     {
        //Creates ArrayList
        //ArrayList<Integer> visit_floors = new ArrayList  <Integer>(); 
        //Creates Passenger Threads
        for(int i=1;i<numThreads;++i)
        {
            passengerT[i] = new Thread(new Person(i,RandomFloor()));
            passengerT[i].start();
            try {
                passengerT[i].join();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
}
```

**Person**

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    public class Person implements Runnable {

        //Defines person
        int passenger;
        int floor;
        private int numThreads = 49;
        Elevator e = new Elevator();
        //Defines the sem with 7 keys to give
        static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(passengerSem());

        public Person(){};

        public Person(int person,int floor)
        {
            this.passenger=person;
            this.floor=floor;
            Simulator.visit_floors.add(floor);
        }
        public void run()
        {

            System.out.println("Person "+passenger+" enters the elevator to go to floor "+floor);

            try
            {

            //Adds permit to elevator
            //wait for key
            Elevator.signalElevator();
            sem.acquire();

            //Give access to the next 7 threads into elevator

            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public static int passengerSem()
        {
            return 6;
        }

    }
```

**Elevator**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

    public class Person implements Runnable {

        //Defines person
        int passenger;
        int floor;
        private int numThreads = 49;
        Elevator e = new Elevator();
        //Defines the sem with 7 keys to give
        static Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(passengerSem());

        public Person(){};

        public Person(int person,int floor)
        {
            this.passenger=person;
            this.floor=floor;
            Simulator.visit_floors.add(floor);
        }
        public void run()
        {

            System.out.println("Person "+passenger+" enters the elevator to go to floor "+floor);

            try
            {

            //Adds permit to elevator
            //wait for key
            Elevator.signalElevator();
            sem.acquire();

            //Give access to the next 7 threads into elevator

            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public static int passengerSem()
        {
            return 6;
        }

    }
```

**Sample Output**

```
Elevator door opens at floor 1
Person 0 enters elevator to go to floor 5
Person 1 enters elevator to go to floor 2
Person 2 enters elevator to go to floor 8
Person 3 enters elevator to go to floor 4
Person 4 enters elevator to go to floor 6
Person 5 enters elevator to go to floor 7
Person 6 enters elevator to go to floor 2
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 2
Person 1 leaves elevator  
Person 6 leaves elevator  
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 4
Person 3 leaves elevator  
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 5
Person 0 leaves elevator  
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 6
Person 4 leaves elevator  
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 7
Person 5 leaves elevator  
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 8
Person 2 leaves elevator  
Elevator door closes
Elevator door opens at floor 1
…
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing your homework for you, maybe think about putting the semaphores you need in an array of `n` lists, where `n` is the number of floors. When the person tells the elevator that he / she wants to go to floor `i`, the elevator puts his / her semaphore into the `i`th list. The elevator can then signal all of the semaphores in that list to let the people who are getting off on that floor to leave.